# Netbeans PHP parent class code completion

Tags: php, netbeans

I am using Netbeans for a custom PHP project and code completion does not work properly. Any help will be wonderful. This is my scenario.

A summary of the View class.

```
use Smarty;

Class View extends Smarty
{
   public function render($template)
   {
       $this->display('$template);
   }
}
```

A summary of the Controller class.

```
use View;

Class Controller
{
   /* @var $view View */
   public $view;

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->view = new View;
   }

   $this->view-> // Netbeans show all methods from View and Smarty Class.
}
```

In my individual Controllers.

```
use Controller;

Class IndexController extends Controller
{
   $this->view-> // Does NOT show anything either from View or Smarty Class.
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What do you mean "custom PHP project"?

Comment: Hi, I mean that is not any of the regular PHP frmaework like Zend, Laravel, etc.